# WebToCase via cURL

Tags: web2case

Is it possible to create a Case via cURL?
When i'm sending the cURL i'll get this response:

```
Status Code:200 OK
Is-Processed:true Exception:common.exception.SalesforceGenericException
```

UPDATE:

I want to create a case via php cURL.

This is the URL to Salesforce:

```
https://cs27.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8&origid=id&submit=submit&case_source=Web2Case&key1=value1&key2=value2&sonstiges=HTTP/1.1
```

Status Code:

```
200 OK
```

Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Sat, 30 Jan 2016 22:43:46 GMT
Is-Processed:true Exception:common.exception.SalesforceGenericException
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

The problem is, that the case won't be created and i don't know why. Maybe you can help me.

Thanks,
Christopher

Comment: Welcome to SE. While asking any question it is always good to add as much information as you can add with your question including your code. It will help others to point out exact error.

Comment: @Himanshu, thanks for your hint. I updated and extended my question.

Comment: you could use the standard SFDC REST API (POST) API to create a `Case` where POST body is JSON for the various Case fields

Comment: It's seems like you are hitting internal sfdc url instead of using API which will not work. You should use REST api to insert lead.

Comment: When i have to use the REST API i need SSL, right?

Comment: you don't need any SSL you can directly use that. google about the rest API in salesforce